# Unidentified Index using condition to pass value

Tags: php

I have a problem,

```
if($_POST['carrier'] == 'LBC') {
    $_POST['payment'] =='BPI';
}
else if($_POST['carrier'] == 'PickUp') {
    $_POST['payment'] == 'PickUp';
}

if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $_POST['payment'];
}
```

my `$_POST['payment']` is causing an unidentified index problem but my carrier is not, maybe because i used a form using the carrier on the previous page.

how do i fix this problem? because i need to pass the value for the payment. only the carrier is passed from the previous form, but here in this page, i need to pass a value to the `$_POST` or at least in the `$_SESSION` but it does not work for me.

i dont know what's wrong.

Comment: change this  $_POST['payment'] =='BPI'; to  $_POST['payment'] ='BPI'; and  $_POST['payment'] =='BPI';  to  $_POST['payment'] ='BPI';

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php **vs.** http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you must use the `$_POST` that way, its only going to be set on form submission.

```
$payment = null;
if($_POST['carrier'] == 'LBC'){
    $payment = 'BPI';
}

else if($_POST['carrier'] == 'PickUp'){
    $payment = 'PickUp';
          // ^ assignment operator (=) not (==) equality
}

if (isset($_POST['order'])){
    $_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $payment;
}
```

Comment: @VinceAgno sure tol glad this helped

Comment: Actually he CAN use post like this. He just had a operator problem. On the other hand, yes... he should not use post like this.